# i can't import GLTFLoader in use Nestjs

Tags: node.js, typescript, import, three.js, nestjs

i have file with import GLTFLoader from threejs and he works fine when run only in node, but if i import this file to nestjs i get error.

```
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader'; //i get Error: Cannot find module '/home/notahero/generatorBack/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader'
```

node version v18.17.1
three 0.156.1
@types/three 0.156.0

i try add .js but get another error

```
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js'; //i get Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module
```